# Would proxying ssh be insecure

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, network-security

If I would use something for remote port forwarding like ngrok, or Serveo:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:22 serveo.net
```

Would this pose a treat to my security since there is a man in the middle?

How would I be able to do something like this, in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't open a port up to the Internet, set up your own server, like a cheap VPS, and forward traffic via SSH via that.